# error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<...>

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, unique-ptr

I'm new to C++ programming. I was trying to use an external library where i have access to header files an .so libraries.

here is my library code

```
class Employee {
private:
      std::unique_ptr<Address> address;
      ................
      ................
      ................
public:
     virtual void updateAddressCity(cont string& city){ address.updateCity(city); }
}
```

i was trying to initialize this employee variable within my class constructor and i was facing this error

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<...>

**EmployeeInfo.h**

```
class EmployeeInfo{
private:
Employee mEmployee;

public:
Employee getEmployee();
}
```

**EmployeeInfo.cpp**

```
EmployeeInfo::EmployeeInfo(Employee &employee) : mEmployee(employee) {

}
```

Comment: You should be getting errors for `address.updateCity(city)`, as `address` is a *pointer* to an object, not an object instance itself. Please try to create a [mcve] which replicates the error you ask about and don't contain other unrelated errors. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question, and add a comment in the code where the errors are.

Comment: As for the error you ask about, think about what `getEmployee` is really returning... It's returning a *copy* of an `Employee` object, and because `Employee` contains a `std::unique_ptr` member, it can't be copied.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Address>` has no function called `updateCity`. u may use `->` instead of `.` and I think this is not the code gives the given error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found a solution thanks for taking time to answer my question

**Solution** 
marked
`Employee mEmployee;` as a reference

`Employee& mEmployee;`